# SQL Server 2012 Failure: when Importing flat file and DATES are in FORMAT of YYYY.M.DD

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-schema

Help!  I have tons of data already in these date formats (YYYY.M.DD), so I can't modify the data.  Is there an easy fix?  I'm getting conversion issues when I presently try to import the current dates as a "Date" field.

I'm using Tableau as an overlay and it recognized the dates correctly, no problem.  What can I do?

Comment: Import into a varchar column first (e.g. into a staging table), then perform a conversion before moving them to the real table.

Comment: Questions ***must*** **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: The problem is largely around SQL server not recognizing the date format of (YYYY.M.DD).  Any way around this?

Comment: Here is the SQL code SQL Server is spitting out:                                        `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[20130421] (
[MEMID] bigint,
[TRANSACTION_DATE] datetime
)`   I need to convert my date from YYYY.M.DD to something SQL (Server) will recognize.  How would I change the code when first importing this data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a programmers editor, or sed (if you have Cygwin tools installed) to do a regular expression replace on the date strings, since the pattern is quite distinctive (and all you would need to do is replace the period with dashes to do a bulk import, which is what I'm assuming you're trying to do).

Failing to do that, is there an OleDB driver for Tableau?   You could import the flat files into Tableau, and then from there to SQL Server...

Comment: Would any of the alternative data types recognize the YYYY.M.DD date format?  Or could I import it as text stream in MYSQL, and then let Tableau worry about it when I pull the data from MySQL?

Comment: I suspect that importing it as a varchar instead of a typed date would probably work:  do a pilot test (and let us know how it works).